# How can I write the long line in two different lines in table?

Tags: tables

Hello Can some one tell me how can i Write long lines in two or three lines in table. I did the following

```
\newline
\begin{table}[thb]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3.5cm}||p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|   }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{HE} \\
 \hline
 parameter&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{X} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Y}\\
 \hline
 & \makecell{A} & \makecell{D} &\makecell{A} & \makecell{B}\\
 \hline
comment  &short line    &h_2, N_2, CO_2, CO, H_2O, MeOH     &_2, N_2, CO_2, CO, H_2O, MeOH\\
 Phase&  Shortline  & This is very long line & This is very long line    &This is very long line\\
 
 \hline

\end{tabular}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Which is the long line?

Comment: Please add a sketch of the desired output. Currently it is unlear which "long line"  you are referring to.

Comment: Don't use math mode for chemical formulae. Instead use an appropriate package such as `chemmacros` or `mhchem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to properly typeset the chemical formulae, I have used the `chemmacros` package. In order to avoid large white spaces that are introduced since `p` type columns are justified by default, I have left aligned the contents of column 3 and 4. To do so, you can either add `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}` right before the column specifier of the column you want to left align or you can define a new column, as I have done for the fourth column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{chemmacros} % Provides the \ch command

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[thb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3.5cm}||p{2cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|R{2cm}|p{2cm}|   }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{HE} \\
 \hline
 parameter&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{X} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Y}\\
 \hline
 & \makecell{A} & \makecell{D} &\makecell{A} & \makecell{B}\\
 \hline
comment  &short line    & \ch{H2}, \ch{N2}, \ch{CO2}, \ch{CO}, \ch{H2O}, \ch{MeOH}   & \ch{H2}, \ch{N2}, \ch{CO2}, \ch{CO}, \ch{H2O}, \ch{MeOH}   &\\
 Phase&  Shortline  & This is very long line & This is very long line    &This is very long line\\
 
 \hline

\end{tabular}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have limited my answer only to the row containing the chemical formula which seems the troublesome part-- I think something is also missing in the begining of the contents of the fourth column `{_2, N_2, CO_2, CO, H_2O, MeOH}`

Do note there is one additional column added by you which is not used

Add `\usepackage{chemfig}` in the preamble

[image]

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{3.5cm}||p{2cm}|l|l|p{2cm}|   }
        
        comment  &short line    & \chemfig{h_2, N_2, CO_2, CO, H_2O, MeOH}     & 
        \chemfig{_2, N_2, CO_2, CO, H_2O, MeOH}\\
        
        
    
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Comment: The `chemfig` package might not be the best choice here. While it is true that one can produce molecular formulae with this package, its main purpose is providing possibilities to draw structural formulae. Also, placing all formulae into a single `\chemfig` command (and in an `l` type column)  prevents linebreaks alltogether, which seems to be the opposite of what the OP wanted to achieve, at least judging from "write the long line in two different lines" in the title of the question.